# Using extensions to give a value to an existing property

Tags: swift

I want all `UINavigationBar` objects to have a default value of `[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Soft Elegance", size: 18)!]` in it's `titleTextAttributes` property.

In a `UIViewController`, this is how I would set it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Soft Elegance", size: 18)!]
}
```

However, I have several `UIViewControllers` that all require this line of code. I know that `extensions` can provide behaviours for the entire class, but I'm failing to make this happen for my case:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
  var titleTextAttributes: [NSObject: AnyObject]! {
    return [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Soft Elegance", size: 18)!]
  }
}
```

Are there any ways to accomplish this via `extensions`?

Comment: How about using the `appearance` proxy? e.g. `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Soft Elegance" size:18]}];`

Comment: Definitely something I did not know, and will now use :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `UIAppearance`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Soft Elegance", size: 18)!]
```

This will affect all UINavigationBars in the app.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html), **Extensions** in Swift can:

- Add computed properties and computed type properties
- Define instance methods and type methods
- Provide new initializers
- Define subscripts
- Define and use new nested types
- Make an existing type conform to a protocol

**Extensions** is used to *extent/add* new behaviours, what you need is to override the default behaviours. You can achieve this by subclass `UINavigationBar`or `UIViewController` like,

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Soft Elegance", size: 18)!]
    }
}
```

Then use `BaseViewController` to replace existing `UIViewController`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid subclassing. It's not as efficient as extensions and I'd end up having a complex web of subclasses when all I want to do is to make 1 change that can influence all subsequent invocations of the class.

Your method is definitely a way to accomplish what I want - I just want to fully utilize Swift extensions. Doesn't look like it's possible eh?